# Get user info for when deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

MVC5 .Net 4.6.1

I have the following code to get the currently logged in Windows user:

```
 var windowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
  var value = windowsIdentity.Name;//returns SYSTEMS\\CJones
```

Works like a charm when running locally. I deploy my site to Azure and now this exact code returns:

```
  azurewebappname_ee6a
```

Of course this will not work. Does anyone know how to get the currently logged in windows user so the Azure web app will not be detected instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like some service principal. You are deploying to the Web Apps, and, as it is a service, there is no such functionality as "someone logged in" - you simply cannot go and connect to the underlying OS - it is the different model, especially if web app is in something like a shared mode.

If you need to implement such functionality, virtual machine deployment looks like a more appropriate option.

Comment: This makes sense...I'm looking for any kind of work around to get the user

Comment: For what? Could you please elaborate the scenario? I think, max you may get in Web Apps from that is some service principal that have no sense in external world

Comment: Elaborate? All i want is the current user who's logged into their machine. Thats straight forward.  I cant do it the way I described, so I'm looking for another way. If you don't know of one, its fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said this is because the web app is in a shared model. You would need to add some level of authentication to the web app as described in this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-websites-authentication-authorization/). Then use the appropriate API to retrieve the data of the user that is logged in.

Lots of integration methods for authentication exist so it's difficult to give examples for all of them. Just to add that as it's an Internet zone URL you are visiting then the username won't be exposed, that's why it's not working technically in short (just in case you wondered).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I found the solution. I setup a new MVC project and clicked "Change Authentication"...I selected "Work and School" and the URI for my company came up and VS2015 did all the OWIN swcurity stuff. So some things were in place that I needed. Thanks

Comment: Awesome glad it helped 